# In Google Slides, trying to set AutofitType to 'Shrink text on overflow' ('TEXT_AUTOFIT')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I have tried the following code but discovered that although the AutofitTypes are enumerated, only "NONE" works.

```
      requests = [(
        { updateShapeProperties: {
            objectId: shape.getObjectId(),
            shapeProperties: {
              autofit: {
                autofitType: "NONE" // vs. "TEXT_AUTOFIT"
              }
            },
            fields: "autofit.autofitType"
          }
        }
      )]
      response = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, deck.getId());
```

So I changed my logic and created the TEXT_BOX in Slides with the desired AutofitType. To my chagrin, when I issued my first shape.getText().replaceAllText('text placeholder','new text'), the Autofit option has been reset to NONE.

Any thoughts on how I can script the setting of AutofitType?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `To my chagrin, when I issued my first shape.getText().replaceAllText('text placeholder','new text'), the Autofit option has been reset to NONE.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: After manually setting the Autofit option, when I ran test code, I determined that the replaceAllText command reset the Autofit option to NONE.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand your situation. In this case, your situation has already been reported to Google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191389037 Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that your goal is not still resolved. I apologize for this. So, how about adding a star to the issue tracker?